# Fn keys in xmonad on dell xps 15

Tags: dell, brightness, xmonad

I just got new Dell XPS 15 and install ubuntu 16.04 with XMonad. And all works just well except <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys. Keyboard backlight can be enabled by <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>, but other buttons, like <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> or <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> (decrease and increase brightness) don't work.

Under Unity all <kbd>Fn</kbd> key works fine.

Which config can I use to enable <kbd>Fn</kbd> key under XMonad?

Answer (score 7):

You have to add custom keybindings to your xmonad config file. The keycodes are `XF86MonBrightnessUp` and `XF86MonBrightnessDown`. Then you have to use something like [lux](https://github.com/Ventto/lux).

Here is how i use it:

```
  import XMonad
  import XMonad.Hooks.DynamicLog
  import XMonad.Hooks.ManageDocks
  import XMonad.Util.EZConfig(additionalKeys, additionalKeysP)
  import XMonad.Util.Run(spawnPipe)
  import XMonad.Config.Desktop
  import XMonad.Config.Gnome
  import XMonad.Hooks.ManageHelpers
  import System.IO
  import Graphics.X11.ExtraTypes.XF86

  main = do
    xmproc <- spawnPipe "tint2"
    nm <- spawnPipe "nm-applet"
    xmonad $ desktopConfig
      { modMask = myModMask
      , terminal = "termite"
      , borderWidth = 1 
      , layoutHook = avoidStruts $ layoutHook defaultConfig
      , manageHook = manageHook defaultConfig <+> manageDocks
      } `additionalKeysP` myKeys

  myModMask = mod4Mask -- Use Super instead of Alt

  myKeys =  [ ("<XF86AudioRaiseVolume>", spawn "pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ +1.5%")
            , ("<XF86AudioLowerVolume>", spawn "pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@  -1.5%")
            , ("<XF86AudioMute>", spawn "pactl set-sink-mute @DEFAULT_SINK@ toggle")    

            , ("<XF86AudioPlay>", spawn "playerctl play-pause")    
            , ("<XF86AudioPrev>", spawn "playerctl previous")    
            , ("<XF86AudioNext>", spawn "playerctl next")    

            , ("<XF86MonBrightnessUp>", spawn "lux -a 5%")    
            , ("<XF86MonBrightnessDown>", spawn "lux -s 5%")    
            ]
```

I hope this helps you.